# Javascript get an animation to follow a path and saving canvas state

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, promise

A basic [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpngwxys/27/)

The main goal is to get the penguin to walk right down the line, then left back up. In general, I need it to walk along the path in the correct direction, but for this basic example I just need to figure this out and I can extend it to my paths. As shown in the fiddle, the paths are set like an array of coordinates like `[{x:n,y:m}]`. I also need `penguin_wrap` to be a promise as it is being used with `await` in my code, but the big issue I seem to be having is that when I run my code, the line gets erased and the penguin runs. In the fiddle, for some reason, this isnt being reproduced so as long as I can figure out how to move it properly I should be able to figure it out.

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmj5yqed/39/) that shows it walking along a path, but I cant seem to apply it when the canvas is drawn underneath. Quick note, I need to save the state of the canvas because a line is animated first (using request animationframe and lineTo), which cannot be erased. The penguin needs to walk along the line (path)

Thank you

Comment: you see the error of course ....`TypeError: resolve is not a function` `penguin_right.onload = resolve;` because you want onload to get a function, not the result of immediately calling one

Comment: and then you'll have an issue with `context` being undefined, because finalArr is `[context, [array of points]]` and your reduce method doesn't know this

Comment: and once you fix this, then `frame` is `undefined`

Comment: and your second fiddle ... eventually gets `TypeError: path[(counter + 1)] is undefined` - these are all things that are easily debugged by yourself, if only you used the brwoser **developer** tools console :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Some good catches, I didnt think to check the console in the fiddle when I wrote it. I fixed those and the same thing is happening however, nothing shows up. I am getting a weird `bind` error, but it isnt in my code so im thinking is a library somewhere. Updated the fiddle

Comment: no errors in your fiddle, and you haven't loaded any libraries

Comment: `if ((++frame) % 4 > 0) return;` stops everything before it starts!

Comment: was that supposed to be `if ((++frame) % 4 > 0) return requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);`

Comment: @JaromandaX That didnt work, but it made me realize I had put `if ((++frame) % 4 > 0) return ` before any call to `requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);`. Switching `requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);` to the top and having `if ((++frame) % 4 > 0) return ` after it works perfectly. Thanks again for the help!